# libraries for file metadata in typescript

Tags: typescript, file, npm, metadata, lib

I am currently building a web tool for reading and changing file metadata. I am still searching for good libraries that can handle reading and altering the metadata of all types of files.

If you know of any such libraries, I would appreciate it if you could share them with me.